# How to remove a little "connection" between clips in 2 tracks in iMovie?

Tags: imovie

[image]

This is the square I mean. I know what is it for. It means that two clips have strong connection in these particular places. But now I need to remove these relative connection:-) The question is **HOW**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Audio tracks are attached to a specific video clip.

You can move them though: hold ⌥⌘ and click somewhere on the audio clip.

Comment: It is not about audio tracks. It is about a little green **rectangle** within yellow boundaries.

Comment: @Bartłomiej It's because of the audio track. It's a connection triangle from the audio track underneath. It indicates that the audio track is connected to that video clip at that point.

Comment: Why would it allow me to move the audio clip all along but not detach it completely?!

Answer (score 0):

You can put the clip behind it in its place (replace it) then delete the clip and move audio back to the beginning. That worked for me. They should make it better it's ok for very simple projects.